# Ember CLI Mirage: 2 level sideloaded response

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I'm having some difficulty with modeling this relationship. Can someone please help?

> A Tenant has an App
>
> An App has a Brand

The big gotcha is 2 levels of side loading. My current API returns a response as follows:

```
{
  "tenants": [
      {
        "app_id": "app_001",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Illya_no_delete",
      }
    ],
  "app": [
    {
      "brand_id": "brand_001",
      "id": "app_001",
      "name": "updated test client 2 name",
    }
  ],
  "brands": [
    {
      "id": "brand_001",
      "app_id": "app_001"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've set my **models** as:

```
// models/tenant.js
export default Model.extend({
  app: belongsTo('app'),
});


// mirage/models/app.js
export default Model.extend({
  brand: belongsTo('brand'),
  tenant: belongsTo('tenant')
});

// mirage/models/brand.js
export default Model.extend({
  app: belongsTo('app')
});
```

I've set my **serializers** as:

```
// mirage/serializers/app.js
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  include: ['brand']
});

// mirage/serializers/tenant.js
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  include: ['app']
});
```

I've set my **scenario** as:

```
// mirage/scenarios/default.js
let brand = server.create('brand');
let app = server.create('app', {brand: brand});
server.createList('tenant', 10, {app: app});
```

Unfortunately my generated response does NOT return a side-loaded brand object. I see all my other objects:

```
{
  tenant: {
    id: 1,
    app_id: 2
  },
  apps: [
    {
      id: 2,
      brand_id: null,
      tenant_id: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions on what I need to do to get 'brands' to appear?

Comment: One-to-one relationships are not currently properly supported (it's in the works), for now I would suggest removing one side of the relationship and using the [serialize hook](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/serializers/#serializeresponse-request) to do any final munging. `belongsTo` makes an assumption that the other side is `hasMany`.

Comment: Thank you @SamSelikoff ! Really appreciate the answer. I think I got a working solution. Will post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested, here's a solution that worked for me based on Sam Selikoff's comment. Open to feedback:

**Models:**

```
// models/tenant.js
export default Model.extend({
  app: belongsTo('app'),
  brand: belongsTo('brand'),
});

// mirage/models/app.js
export default Model.extend({
  tenant: belongsTo('tenant')
});

// mirage/models/brand.js
export default Model.extend({

});
```

**Serializers:**

```
// mirage/serializers/tenant.js
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  include: ['app', 'brand'],

  serialize() {
    let json = ApplicationSerializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);
    if (json.brands.length > 0) {
      let brandId = json.brands[0].id;
      json.applications[0].brand_id = brandId;
    }
    return json;
  }
});
```

**Default Scenario:**

```
// mirage/scenarios/default.js
let brand = server.create('brand');
let app = server.create('app');
server.createList('tenant', 10, {app: app, brand: brand});
```

**Response:**

```
{
  tenant: {
    id: 1,
    app_id: 2
  },
  apps: [
    {
      id: 2,
      brand_id: 3,
      tenant_id: 1
    }
  ],
  brand: [
    {
      id: 3
    }
  ]
}
```